# Is there a name for an affine $\Bbbk$-scheme whose $\Bbbk$-algebra is finite dimensional as a vector space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there a name for an affine $\Bbbk$-scheme whose $\Bbbk$-algebra is finite dimensional as a vector space? From what I understand 'finite type' is reserved for finite generation as algebras, not only vector spaces...

Comment: Such a scheme is called finite over k, cf. stacks project tag 0563.

Comment: Finite length, Artinian, zero-dimensional are probably also the same. (I have not evaluated these statements at all.)